# Wrong charset in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, utf

I have a page with forms to add or edit a entry to a mysql-database. Everything works fine, the form shows everything right, the output on the page is right.

Only when I open the mysql-database (phpMyAdmin) the entries are shown wrong. Some german letters are wrong.

For example `AndrÃ©` instead of `André`. Or `groÃŸ` instead of `groß`.

The Output on the page works fine. Also the edit-function in an HTML-form works fine. 
I just don't understand why everything is written wrong in the database.

All my PHP-Page are in "utf-8".

Comment: mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

When you create a database, you can set CHARACTER SET by utf8.

Example:

```
  CREATE DATABASE tablename 
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Make sure your database has UTF8 char set as well

You can convert you existing table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Header to the top of your php code. This will set encoding of content.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

You can use any encoding, which is set in your database instead of`utf-8`.